# npm bootstrap-rtl for angular-2 cli project

Tags: npm, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have angular2-cli project.
I use bootstrap 3 for the ui.

Now I need to support rtl.

I see In this link that I can add bootstrap-rtl by npm.
Is it match to angular-2 cli project also?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-rtl-ondemand

Answer (score 2):

you must first install `ng-bootstrap` for angular-2

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap bootstrap --save
```

then you must add ng-bootstrap in ngModule:

```
import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
...
@NgModule({
...
imports: [AlertModule.forRoot(), ... ],
... 
})
```

then you must install rtl-bootstrap from npm:

```
npm install bootstrap-rtl
```

and at last you must open angular-cli.json and insert a new entry into the styles array :

```
 "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap-rtl/dist/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css",
       ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this standard patch for both `Bootstrap 3` or `Bootstrap 4`
[RTL Bootstrap](https://github.com/parsmizban/RTL-Bootstrap)